# image editor for php website

Tags: php, jquery, image, editor

I have to create website in PHP, which need image editor functionality like image makeup, resizing, crop, flipping, rotating etc.

if any one knows this type of editor or website having such functionality please let me know.

example link this : http://www.phpimageeditor.se/phpimageeditor/index.php?imagesrc=sample.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use PHP GD Library.

want some examples and GD image functions, it is given in following link

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PhpThumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/) which can provide these functionalities.